# List of lists: add all items in each list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I want to write an if-statement for this list:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

lst= ([[a, b, c] for a in range(0,x+1) for b in range(0,y+1) for c in range(0,z+1)])`
```

I want to add a, b and c in all lists and if they are not equal to n, print each of them. How should I do that?

Comment: can you explain a bit more with taking one set of input and corresponding output as example ?

Comment: for example if we set all x,y and z as 1, and n as 2, then the list could have [0,0,0], [0,0,1] ... but it can't have [0,1,1] because sum of x,y and z will be equal to n.

Comment: what if you set x,y,z to  2, 3,4 but n = 2 ?

Comment: as long as sum of x+y+z is not equal to n, it should print the list.

Comment: got it . i will add one answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an `if condition` in list comprehension , which makes this easy to achieve

```py
lst= ([[a, b, c] for a in range(0,x+1) for b in range(0,y+1) for c in range(0,z+1) if a+b+c != n])
```

Comment: did that, the error said that I haven't defined a, b and c..

Comment: note that if condition is inside the square bracket

Comment: can you post your complete code or link to its image so that i can see how that error is coming

Comment: didn't pay attention to the fact that if-statement is in the bracket the first time.

Comment: great that you were able to fix it

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = []

for a in range(0, x + 1):
  if a != n:
    print(a)
    lst.append(a)

for b in range(0, y + 1):
  if b != n:
    print(b)
    lst.append(b)


for c in range(0, z + 1):
  if c != n:
    print(c)
    lst.append(c)
```

You can use if statement inside list comprehension but not in this context because you will need an else statement

Comment: Thank you, but I want a+b+c != n somehow.. maybe I can use your way but do the if-statement at the end?

Answer (score 0):

A `filter` & `itertools` approach:

```py
> a, b, c, n = 1, 1, 1, 2
> all_combos = itertools.product(range(a+1), range(b+1), range(c+1))
> lst = list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) != n, all_combos))
> print(lst)
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```